# List of inherited objects - C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

In my program I have a Base class with many inherited classes. I need to store a list of these inherited objects (or any container). The only way I can think of to do this is by having a list of the Base class with some type enumeration and then down casting to the inherited type.

Having to constantly cast my objects seems like a heavy penalty for just trying to have my objects in some container.

Are there any other options? Is casting not as bad as it seems?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why do you need to cast them to their base type? You should probably use a virtual function instead.

Comment: I didn't think it was possible to call inherited methods while only having a reference to the base class. Would it not just call the base method? I thought I would need to cast to the inherited class to call its virtual methods. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes you're wrong, if the base method is marked "virtual", the inherited method will always be called.

Comment: Interesting. I may not even need to cast then. Thanks for the knowledge David and Jem.

Comment: For that to work, you need to store pointers (preferably smart pointers) in your list, not actual objects.  Otherwise, the derived objects have to be actually copied into the list, and they get "sliced" into base objects in the process.

Comment: @Wyzard or references, if appropriate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use polymorphism via virtual functions, that's what they're there for:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  virtual void print() {
    cout << "This is an A object" << endl;
  }
};

class B : public A {
public:
  virtual void print() {
    cout << "This is a B object" << endl;
  }
};

class C : public A {
public:
  virtual void print() {
    cout << "This is a C object" << endl;
  }
};

class D : public B {
  // empty
};

int main() {
  std::list<A*> objects;
  objects.push_back(new A());
  objects.push_back(new B());
  objects.push_back(new C());
  objects.push_back(new D());

  for_each(objects.begin(), objects.end(), mem_fun(&A::print));

  return 0;
}

// outputs:
// This is an A object
// This is a B object
// This is a C object
// This is a B object
```

Comment: This example has numerous syntax errors, and also doesn't work.  Copying derived instances (rather than pointers) into a `list<A>` slices them into base instances.

Comment: Fixed. Was multitasking and not paying close attention.

Comment: I added the necessary includes so that it'll actually compile.  Also, note to other readers, `mem_fn` requires C++11 or TR1.

Comment: Also, `std::list<std::unique_ptr<A>>` or not dynamically allocating objects would be better, but the general idea is there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no directly supported way of programmatically getting a list of all of the subclasses of a base class.

You can do it in your code by having each sub class "announce" itself by registering via a call to some function, and get that function to accept/store the needed data.

However if you are constantly casting objects from a base class to a derived class then perhaps you are not making the best use of polymorphism.